# Solution to Work Around Limited Number of Characters Sent in API Request?

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am trying to come up with a solution to work around the limited number of characters which can be sent within the Power Bi API.  The current limitation is 4,000 characters per value for string column in POST rows operation.  If I import a CSV with more than 4,000 characters, I receive the limitation error.  Could there be a possible way to loop through 4,000 characters at a type per POST request until the CSV is fully imported?

I have tried solely entering in one column at a time in the `-type` field. Example( `{"NessusScannedShort.PluginID"="string";}`)  The idea is to iterate through each column value via a loop with a new value within `-type` every time.  This method did not work, instead, it imported every column in.

```
while($true)
{
    # Iterate each CSV file and send to PowerBI

    Get-ChildItem "$currentPath\Combination" -Filter "*.csv" |% { 

        $file = $_               

        #Import csv and add column with filename

        $data = Import-Csv $file.FullName | select @{Label="File";Expression={$file.Name}}, @{Label="FileDate";Expression={[System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}}, *

        # Send data to PowerBI

        $data | Out-PowerBI -authToken $authToken -dataSetName "NessusScannedShortV2" -tableName "NessusScan1406V3" `
            -types @{"NessusScannedShort.PluginID"="string"; "NessusScannedShort.CVE"="string"; "NessusScannedShort.CVSS"="string"} `
            -batchSize 100 -ForceTableSchemaUpdate -verbose

        # Archive the file

        Move-Item $file.FullName "$currentPath\Combination\Archive" -Force
    }

    Write-Output "Sleeping..."

    Sleep -Seconds 5
}
```

Here is the error limitation message I receive when importing more than 4,000 characters.

> Invoke-PBIRequest : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad
>   Request.   String value cannot exceed 4000 characters"}}'

Comment: This "sounds" like a limitation on a data type. Do you have any control over the data type used on the destination side? In SQL, for example, nchar and nvarchar have maximum lengths of 4000, but varchar allows up to 8000 and nvarchar(max) has an extremely high limitation.

Comment: If you try something like `$data.column3 | Out-PowerBI`, `$data.column4 | Out-PowerBI`, `$data.column5 | Out-PowerBI`, etc., does that yield a favorable result? I think you have three options here: 1) Send a subset of columns at a time into `Out-PowerBI`. 2) Reconstruct `$data` differently before sending to `Out-PowerBI`. 3) Change the destination data type to support more characters

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly.  Your help is greatly appreciated, seriously...  I just tried idea one where you extract one column at a time.  This idea may work, but each time I send a subset in, the previous subset is replaced with the new one.  It appears the `-types` field will replace each time.  I am going to look into the other two ideas before I try to play around with '-types'